# Load and modify a tkinter gui from a pickle file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pickle

I have some trouble loading a GUI interface from a pickle file.

I was able to do what I want but it doesn't work exactly as I expected and I'm not sure it is the correct way.

This is a reduced example of the basic gui (you don't really have to read it and understand it depth, it is not the main question):

```
tableRel = {}
master = Tk()
tableOrders = pickle.load(open(r"\\VIERNES7-3\Documentos c\sharedTableOrders.p","rb"))


count = 0
lOfKeys = tableOrders.keys()
numOfTables = len(lOfKeys)
for rowN in range((numOfTables /10)+1): 
        for colN in range(10):
            if count == numOfTables:
                break
            tableN = (colN+1)+(10*(rowN))


            f = Frame(master,height=600,width=200, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
            f.grid(row=rowN, column=colN, pady=15, padx= 0)
            Label(f, text="Mesa: " + str(lOfKeys[count])).pack(side = TOP)

            scrollbar = Scrollbar(f, orient=VERTICAL)
            listbox = Listbox(f, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, width=19)

            tableRel[listbox] = lOfKeys[count]

            scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
            scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
            listbox.pack(side=TOP)
            listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", hideOrder)
            listbox.bind("<Return>", hideOrder)

            index = 0
            listbox.delete(0, END)
            for y in tableOrders[lOfKeys[count]]["orders"]:
                #print tableOrders[x]
                if (y["kitchen"] == "si" or y["category"] != "Bebidas") and y["ready"] == "no":
                    listbox.insert(END, y["name"])
                    #ordersByIndex[index] = y["name"]
                    if y["canceled"] == "si":
                        listbox.itemconfig(index, bg="red")
                    #tablesByIndex[index] = x             
                    index += 1


            count += 1


loadFile()
mainloop()
```

Now this is the part where I'm confused, I'm not understanding correctly the concept of the `mainloop()` that is an infinite loop.

What exactly does it do over and over again?

What troubles me, it that if I put a print statement anywhere on the file, it is not printed over and over again, so it is not re-executing the code of the file.

What I basically what to achieve is that after some period of time, the gui reloads and if there are changes in the picke file then the gui updates.

I was able to achieve that by putting my code in a function (let's call it `updateGUI`) and doing `master.after(5000, updateGUI)`.

This doesn't seem to be the best solution because everything changes suddenly (the selected option in the listbox and the scroll) but I guess this could all be solved by remembering the state and imposing it.

But I am wondering if there is some way to take advantage of the mainloop and make the gui "update" when the file has change (it doesn't have to look for changes in the file, it has to update every 10 seconds or so and redraw the screen.)

I have tried `update` and `update_idletasks` but none seems to reload the pickle and re-draw it based on the new information in the pickle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mainloop is where your root widget listens and responds to input and other events, like mouse clicks, keypresses, and signals from the OS.  By using `after`, you *are* taking advantage of mainloop to call your update procedure every *n* seconds.

What you could do in addition is keep track of how long the interface has been idle (no mouse or keyboard events).  If it's idle and there are changes to display, you can update it immediately.  If it's not idle, give the user an indicator and a way to trigger the update manually until it becomes idle again.  This way, the user's work is not interrupted by an update.

Here's a quick example of a timer that resets upon mouse motion or keystrokes.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self, tick):
        self.tick = tick
        self.idle_time = 0

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=100, height=100)
        frame.bind_all("<Motion>", self.reset_idle)
        frame.bind_all("<Key>", self.reset_idle)
        frame.pack()

        self.root.after(self.tick, self.update_timer)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_timer(self):
        print('Idle for %sms' % self.idle_time)
        self.idle_time += self.tick
        self.root.after(self.tick, self.update_timer)

    def reset_idle(self, event):
        self.idle_time = 0

app = App(1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer sorry for the delay, I was trying things out. My only question would be if you could direct me (if you know) to any example of code where it keeps track of user events like mouse movements or clicks. I'm looking for them but maybe you already know a good example.